# Converting Zip to 7zip...Bash Script, or (Linux) Command Line

Tags: bash, zip

Could it be possible to make the below code recursive? Or even better, convert the zips or rar archived files to 7z without extracting the archived files at all? Meaning, I use something like:

```bash
arepack -e -F 7z *.zip
rm -f *.zip
```

but I have nested zip and some other archived files like rar files too

With my code, I have to first extract the zip, (where there are additional zip files in folders - nested zips) I then have to open the terminal in each of those folders and run the extractor.sh file to extract the zips and convert to 7z (and when those have been extracted/converted, I right click the original archive, and compress to 7z using the linux gui). I want to be able to just start at the top most folder and have it convert all the zips to 7z (recursive).

Or even better, could I run arepack without having to extract the zip files and have it iterate through the zip files and convert all the zip and other archives such as rar files inside the original zip to 7z (on the fly?)

Any insight on this would be greatly appreciated!

Best Regards,
Brian

Answer (score 0):

I did not know about arepack tool before, but it cannot be used because the output content is not just repackaged but modified.

It is necessary to extract in a temporary directory, modify the content, and the package again. And do the same inside each temporary directory.

Most compression algorithms can work out of stdin into stdout, and that would give the impression of a possibility of repackaging on the fly, but pesky filenames and other metadata makes it hard to implement something like that. It is possible to do, and maybe someday arepack supports it.

I did not execute the code below. The aunpack and apack calls may require refinement.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Fun academic problem.

set -u # help find undefined variables

# Assume: /var/run is pseudo-filesystem in RAM

repackage()
{
    [[ ! ${1-} ]] && { echo "${FUNCNAME[0]}: called without arg"; exit 1; }
    local input_pkg="$1"
    local input_pkg_basename="${input_pkg#*.}"

    local tmp_dir=$( mktemp --dry-run --directory /var/run/rpgk_tmp_XXXXXX )
    mkdir "$tmp_dir" ||  { echo "${FUNCNAME[0]}: failed to create $tmp_dir"; return; }

    aunpack --extract-to="$tmp_dir" "$input_pkg"

    find "$tmp_dir" -name \*.rar -o -name \*.tar -0 |
        while IFS= read -r -d '' fname; do
            repackage "$fname"
        done

    local dest_fname="$input_pkg_basename".7z
    apack -F 7z "$dest_fname" "$tmp_dir"
    rm -fr "$tmp_dir"
}

repackage "$1"
```

Comment: Hi,

Can you please help me resolve the issue I am having with your code?

Issue: ./convert.sh: line 30: $1: unbound variable

Comment: I am not sure what your code is supposed to do a_w, but according to your message it's not possible to do what I originally asked for. What does your code do if you don't mind me asking?